# При получении строки из ResourceBundle.getBundle непонятные символы

Tags: java, кодировка, locale

Добрый вечер!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему:

```
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.messages", locale, utf8Control);
        try {
            String message = new String(messages.getString(key).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
            pageContext.getOut().write(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Пытаюсь реализовать локализацию, текст получаю из созданного файла messages, проблема заключается в том, что вместо нужных символов выводит "?????? ??????? ????"
Погуглил, проблема видимо с кодировками, попытался всё сделать вот так:

```
String message = new String(messages.getString(key).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

В результате ничего не изменилось...

Comment: какая кодировка у файла ?

Comment: У файла где хранятся переводы слов: ISO-8859-1, на jsp - "UTF-8"

Comment: Ещё я переопределил utf8Control, там переопределил newBundle, и изменил  bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал этот кейс так

```
String subjectTemplate = new String(resourceBundle.
        getString("text").
        getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
```